# check if user tweets or closes window

Tags: jquery, django, twitter

i want to make a ajax call when user clicks the tweet button that appears in dialog box/pop-up.
I open the twitter pop-up with this:

```
function openTwitterModal(){
    twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
        'https://dev.twitter.com/',
        document.getElementById('twitter-btn'),
        {
            text: 'Hello World'
        }
    );
}
```

Can we find out if user really tweets or just closes the pop-up?
Can we run some javascript function when user chooses to share or close the dialog box of twitter? Any django-specific thing that may achieve this purpose?

Comment: No, you cannot. If you could, spamer would use it: tweet me and get a gift...